# How to create API in MVC to access functionality of different site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, single-sign-on

I have two websites, both websites are in MVC 4.0. Suppose the name of websites are A and B. I have added web.Api project in my solution.

My requirement is: when any user registers on website A then it also registers on website B by API, I am new in creating API. Please suggest how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is called [Single Sign-On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) (SSO).  A user can log into a site and the resulting identity can be reused among a number of affiliated sites, e.g. Facebook Connect. You'll want to start looking into [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx) so you can configure your two sites to trust the same Identity Provider.

Be advised, if you're not already familiar with this stuff, there can be a big learning curve. [Programming Windows Identity Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185) by Vittorio Bertocci is a great book on the subject.  He also gives a pretty good presentation [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2010/SIA304) if you can get past his thick Italian accent.